# Tablespace 'XXX_SML_INDEX' does not exist using impdb

Tags: oracle, import, dump

I am new in oracle. I am trying to import an Oracle database from one machine to another by using a dump file. I'm using the below command for the import

> **impdp MOBILETEST/MOBILETEST directory=MOBILETEST
>   dumpfile=MOBILETEST.dmp logfile=MOBILETEST.log full=y;**

I get the error: "tablespace 'XXX_SML_INDEX' does not exist"

> ORA-39083: Object type TABLESPACE_QUOTA failed to create with error:
>   ORA-00959: tablespace 'XXX_SML_INDEX' does not exist Failing sql is:
>   DECLARE   TEMP_COUNT NUMBER;   SQLSTR VARCHAR2(200); BEGIN   SQLSTR :=
>   'ALTER USER "MOBILETEST" QUOTA UNLIMITED ON "XXX_SML_INDEX"';  EXECUTE
>   IMMEDIATE SQLSTR;EXCEPTION   WHEN OTHERS THEN    IF SQLCODE = -30041
>   THEN       SQLSTR := 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM USER_TABLESPACES
>   WHERE TABLESPACE_NAME = ''XXX_SML_INDEX'' AND CONTENTS =
>   ''TEMPORARY''';      EXE ORA-39083: Object type TABLESPACE_QUOTA
>   failed to create with error:

- I am trying to use *remap_tablespace* but dont know where I can get
  second TABLESPACE_QUOTA name, like remap_tablespace=XXX_SML_INDEX: ?

  [image]

Comment: What tablespaces exist on the target database? Have you created any? `select * from DBA_TABLESPACES` will give you a list

Comment: I dont have any tablespace in new database

Comment: of course you have tablespaces in the new database.  You can't have a database without tablespaces.  You say you tried the 'remap_tablespace', but I see no evidence of such in anything you show.

Answer (score 3):

Find the default tablespace at database level (which is not necessarily the default tablespace of your user):

```
SQL>  select property_value from database_properties 
      where property_name = 'DEFAULT_PERMANENT_TABLESPACE';

PROPERTY_VALUE
--------------
USERS
```

Find the default tablespace for your user while logged in another user with adequate privileges for querying `DBA_USERS`:

```
SQL> select default_tablespace from dba_users 
     where username = 'BP';

DEFAULT_TABLESPACE
------------------------------
USERS
```

Find the default tablespace for your user while logged in as that user:

```
SQL> select default_tablespace from user_users;

DEFAULT_TABLESPACE
------------------------------
USERS
```

Using that information, remap the tablespace as: `remap_tablespace=XXX_SML_INDEX:USERS`.

Comment: OR . . . simply create TS XXX_SML_INDEX before running the impdp operation.

Comment: Thanks It work  - Give me response as Job "MOBILETEST"."SYS_SQL_FILE_FULL_01" successfully completed at 15:11:04

Comment: How I can ensure and check all tables is inserted or  not  ?  for this i have try  "select * from T_MAPP_USERMASTER"  but result is "ORA-00942: table or view does not exist "

Comment: @sushantgosavi compare log files from expdp and impdp. It will list table names,size and rows exported/imported

Answer (score 0):

Find the list of existing tablespaces in target database (where you are planning to import), then

```
select distinct tablespace_name from dba_tablespaces;
```

Then use [remap_tablespace](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SUTIL/GUID-F467946E-50B3-4CC0-937A-CC8C18AAF8C1.htm#SUTIL929):

```
impdp MOBILETEST/MOBILETEST directory=MOBILETEST dumpfile=MOBILETEST.dmp logfile=MOBILETEST.log full=y remap_tablespace=XXX_SML_INDEX:CUSTOMER_TS
```